# Trying to hide subcategories which have categories without posts

Tags: archives, categories

On custom archive pages, I want to show subcategories that ***don't*** have their own posts but have sub-subcategories that ***do*** have posts.

And if a child category does not have posts, I want to hide its parent too.

Here is part of the code I'm using:

```
if(is_category() && $has_category_children){ //$has_category_children is true if the current category has subcategories.
    $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'hierarchical' => 0,
        'parent' => $term->term_id,
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach ($categories as $cat) { 
        echo $cat->category_nicename;
    }
}
```

What is the right approach to achieving this?

Comment: Your `categories` having 2 level hierarchy or multilevel hierarchy? Thanks:)

Comment: ^Multilevel hierarchy.

Comment: I tried setting 'hierarchical'=>1....Codex says "When true, the results will include sub-categories that are empty, as long as those sub-categories have sub-categories that are not empty." But that doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ensuring that all parent and grandparent categories are selected for a particular article, instead of just the child category.

That solved my problem. Now, sub-categories that have sub-sub-categories with posts are not treated as "empty".